# Detect what Attributes are set on a controllers action during Application_AuthenticateRequest

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I get a call to `Application_AuthenticateRequest` which I use to perform some authentication logic. Something similar to:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
```

That works generally fine, however in some cases my controller actions have the `AllowAnonymous` attribute attached, and I do not want the code to execute. The is no problem if the user is not logged in, however, if the user is logged in and they attempt to access one of these views, I run into an issue.

What I'm wondering is, if there is a way I can detect what attributes are set on my action in the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` call. Or if I could even detect if the current page requres authentication?

So far I haven't been able to figure this out, but it seems like it should be fairly simple. I'm wondering if someone could point out something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is little old. But I came across to find an answer. I found a solution by using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SkipAuthorization`

This returns true if the action has `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute,
Else this returns false if the action has `[Authorize]` attribute.